# How to get a vigenere table in php?

Tags: php, vigenere

I dont have much experience with php and I'm trying to make a vigenere table but it's returning empty arrays
this is what I have so far:

```
$row= range('a','z');
echo "<table border =\"1\" style='border-collapse: collapse'>";
for ( $row = 1; $row <= 26; $row++) { 
    echo "<tr> ";
    for ($col = 1; $col <= 26; $col++) { 
       $p = range('a','z');
       echo "<td>$p</td> ";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create a table with 26 rows of 26 columns from A-Z? For example...

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+-----+---+---+---+
| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | ... | X | Y | Z |
| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | ... | X | Y | Z |
| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | ... | X | Y | Z |
| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | ... | X | Y | Z |
| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | ... | X | Y | Z |
| ...                                         |
| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | ... | X | Y | Z |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+-----+---+---+---+
```

If that is what you are trying to do, you can do this with the following:

```php
echo '<table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;">';
    foreach (range('a', 'z') as $row_char) {
        echo '<tr>';
            foreach (range('a', 'z') as $col_char) {
                echo '<td>';
                    echo $col_char;
                echo '</td>';
            }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
echo '</table>';
```

Output: https://jsfiddle.net/thelevicole/23tgsoe1/

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with your attempt:

- you set up your range of letters in `$row`, but then overwrite `$row` when you use it as a counter in your outer loop
- in your inner loop you create a new range of letters as an array, but attempt to output them as a string, which raises a PHP Warning on each row.
- Your code doesn't rotate the letters between each row, so the Vigenère cipher simply doesn't work.

Starting with any suitable array you can create the required result with a single loop and careful use of `implode()` to create the rows:

```
declare(strict_types=1);
function vigenere(array $arr){
    $output = "<table>\n";


    // iterate over the array
    foreach($arr as $letter) {
        // Create output row
        $output .= '<tr><td>'.implode('</td><td>',$arr).'</td></tr>'.PHP_EOL;
        // rotate the array for the next row
        $arr[] = array_shift($arr);
    }
    $output .= '</table>';
    return $output;
}

echo vigenere(range("A","Z"));
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/mYEMk